# How to load all pages at startup?

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

With the `Ionic 4` framework and using the `PWA`.

I would like all the pages, the whole project is cached as soon as the first page is loaded.
In fact, I would like the user to log in once and then offline to access all pages.

Because currently, only the first page is displayed ..

Comment: Please, share the code sample and follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about "multiple pages" in a sense that is implying that your implementation does not use the App Shell model.

Probably, you need to do the following things:

1. Implement the App Shell
2. Implement navigation between the different content pages of your app
3. Implement the static content pages (I assume they are static, since you want to primarily use them offline)
4. Have the service worker cache the whole bunch.

All the content is now cached on first launch. Dynamic content fetched from the server would of course still require an internet connection.